# jQuery intelligent event unbind

Tags: event-handling, jquery

I'm trying to intelligently unbind events in jquery so I can easily enable/disalbe them. I'm trying to avoid using state variables because it shouldn't be necessary and it makes my shared functions very cluttered. Here's what I tried initially that didn't work.

```
var dragStart = $('#ruler').mousedown(function(e){
   position = container.offset();
   mousePosition = {
      x: e.pageX,
      y: e.pageY
   };

   var dragging = $(document).mousemove(function(e){
       var x = e.pageX - mousePosition.x;
       var y = e.pageY - mousePosition.y;

       container.offset({
           left: position.left + x,
           top: position.top + y
       });
   });

   var dragStop = $(document).mouseup(function(){
      dragStart.unbind();
      dragging.unbind();
      dragStop.unbind();
   });
});
```

I found out that didn't work because jQuery's event handler functions return references to the element in the selector, and so everything was being unbinded from $(document), which is an issue in my environment.

I know I could come up with function names and do a targeted unbind, but with all the different functions I have to do (more than just shown), this would make the code a pain to go through. Is there any way that allows me functionality similar to what I was going for in the above code? I was thinking something along the lines of this:

```
var foo;
$(<selector>).<eventType>(foo = function(){
   // DO SOMETHING
   $(<unbind button>).click(function(){
      // foo.unbind();
      // OR
      // $(<selector>).unbind(foo);
      // ???????
   });
});
```

I'd be open even to creative solutions. I can get it working right now, but I'm trying to see if I can do it this particular way. Thanks!

Comment: you should use `off` and not `bind` and you should use event namespacing: http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

Comment: If you make that into an answer I'll vote for it. If not I'll make the post myself in a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [namespace](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) you events in a way which gives you more power over them, so if say, you have some king of delegated event `click` going up all the way to the `document` like so:

```
$(document).on('click','a', doSomething);
```

and you might have more like this, which gets delegated all the way to the body, so if you want to remove one of them, you practically kill all the rest, when you unbind the `click` event from the document.

better is:

```
$(document).on('click.someName','a', doSomething);  // bind
$(document).off('click.someName','a');  // unbind
```

imagine also there might be more code on the page which might be using event delegation all the way to the documen,t or some other element, so without namespacing there would be a collusion while binding/unbiding events

Comment: glad it helped because the question was a bit vague :)